# SQL OpenQuery variable tablename

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I need to transfer data from a linked server to our main SQL server. The issue is, that the table name changes everyday.
I have looked around this site to find out if it is even possible to have a variable database name, which it is, but also to see if it is possible to have variables in a `OPENQUERY`, which it also is.

But i am struggling to combine those needs, so i have a variable table name in a `OPENQUERY`.

I need something like this:

```
Declare @LinkedServer as varchar(max) = 'LinkedServer'
Declare @TName as varchar(max) = 'TName'+substring(cast(cast(getdate() as date) as
varchar(50)),1,4)+substring(cast(cast(getdate() as date) as
varchar(50)),6,2)+substring(cast(cast(getdate() as date) as
varchar(50)),9,2)

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(@LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM dbo.@TName')
```

Is there any way i can make a variable table name in a `OPENQUERY` ?

Thank you for your help.

/Mikkel

Comment: Do you have access to create synonyms on the linked server?. preferably create the synonym on the source server, if not the main SQL server could house it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a synonym which gets updated every day before you kick off your data extraction job. Then you don't need to be updating (potentially a tonne of) references.

```
CREATE SYNONYM LinkedTableA
FOR
ServerName.DBName.dbo.TName20170331

SELECT * FROM LinkedTableA
```

Comment: We only have read access on the linked server, we cannot create anything nor can we get tables, databases og Synonyms created on the linked server.

Comment: well try adding this to your main SQL server. you can make a stored procedure to update the synonym name and trigger it each day.

Answer (score 0):

The answer i have, is this:

```
USE [DataBase]
GO

DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[eCallByCallStat]
GO

declare @tablename varchar(50) 

set @tablename = 'Server1..dbo.eCallByCallStat'+substring(cast(cast(getdate()-1 as date) as varchar(50)),1,4)+substring(cast(cast(getdate()-1 as date) as varchar(50)),6,2)+substring(cast(cast(getdate()-1 as date) as varchar(50)),9,2)

declare @sql varchar(500)

set @sql = 'CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[eCallByCallStat] FOR ' + @tablename 

exec (@sql)
```

This will run everymorning updating the table name in the synonym, and then we will insert that data into a prober table so we have all the data.